# how to get first visible row from the table when it is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have 10 row in the table. Out of that only 5 will visible on the screen means when table loads then 1,2,3,4,5 rows are visible . When I scroll down with 1 row then row 2 , 3,4,5,6 are visible . Is there any way in Javascript or jquery to find which is the first  row on the screen ? I have tried may ways like :

```
         if(tr.position().top > $(table).position().top)
         {

         }
         else
         {

         }
```

here I am comparing position of each row and with the table top position . But unfortunately every time I am getting the same position even I scrolled . how to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

Using code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) with some modification:

JS Code (using `div` in place of `tr`):

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var first = null; // element at the top

        $("div").each(function(){ // check each div 
            // if it is visivle, and is there is not first element yet,
            if( isScrolledIntoView($(this)) && !first) {
                first = $(this); // this is the first
                first.addClass("seen"); // visual aspect
            }            
            // unnecessary, only for visual
            else
               $(this).removeClass("seen"); // remove class seen (visual)
        });        

    });

    // foreign code
    function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
        // .....
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H85Lk/1/)**
<sup>Scroll to see effect</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (using JQuery), on a scroll event callback, using a timeout to limit the frequency of the event, plus a cursor of the last found visible element, in way to perform a quicker search on next event. Here 'this' is the context of your view :

```
onScroll: function(e) {
    if (this.scrollEvent) {
        return;
    }

    this.scrollEvent = true;

    setTimeout(function(view) {
        // @replace you should check here is you view still exists using a status on your view context
        if (view.isDestroyed) {
            return;
        }

        view.scrollEvent = false;
        var top = $('youselector on tbody').parent().parent().offset().top;

        if (view.previousTopElement) {
            if (view.previousTopElement.offset().top <= top) {
                // the element is the previous, or on bottom of previous
                var element = view.previousTopElement;
                var i = view.previousTopElementIndex;

                view.previousTopElement = null;

                while (element.length) {
                    if (element.offset().top + element.height() >= top) {
                        // you can uses i + 1 for a 1 based position to display
                        view.previousTopElement = element;
                        view.previousTopElementIndex = i;

                        return;
                    }

                    element = element.next();
                    ++i;
                }
            } else if (view.previousTopElement.offset().top > top) {
                // the element is before the previous
                var element = view.previousTopElement;
                var i = view.previousTopElementIndex;

                this.previousTopElement = null;

                while (element.length) {
                    if (element.offset().top <= top) {
                        // you can uses i + 1 for a 1 based position to display
                        view.previousTopElement = element;
                        view.previousTopElementIndex = i;

                        return;
                    }

                    element = element.prev();
                    --i;
                }
            }
        }

        // no previous, get all rows
        var rows = $('youselector on tbody').children('tr');

        view.previousTopElement = null;
        view.previousTopElementIndex = 0;

        $.each(rows, function (i, el) {
            var element = $(el);

            if (element.offset().top + element.height() >= top) {
                // you can uses i + 1 for a 1 based position to display
                view.previousTopElement = element;
                view.previousTopElementIndex = i;

                return false;
            }
        });
    }, 100, this);   // you can adjust the timeout, pass your view context
}
```

This is the idea. In my case I do this optimisation because I can have many rows.